# Finding a good rendering of the phrase "graphic details"

Tags: traduction, formulation-idiomatique

What would be a  rendering to match of “graphic details”, for instance in a sentence like the following?

> The brawl between the two clans had been set to print in graphic details by a young reporter.

I have the solution “en détails vivides”, “de façon très descriptive”, but those are not quite satisfactory to me.

Comment: Why is it not satisfactory to you? Could you be more specific on what exactly you'd like to express?

Comment: I had a feeling that that was too simplistic, and it seems that 's just the conclusion I reached through the stimulus of comments: it's only a question of choice of details, their particularity as having more import than others on the reader's mind; I think now that it is rather a question of the literary means in making those details interesting, specifically the means of the image, the means that consists in using a word that does not apply factually to the context, only providing an analogy, wherefore my answer "details imagés"; it remains to determine whether I am going too far or not.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand "graphic detail" in English, I wouldn't choose to translate "graphic" litteraly.

I often understand this term to be used as a synonym for "shocking detail", a warning similar to "viewer discretion is advised". (am I correct, btw?). In this case, I would then translate the sentence as follow:

> La bagarre entre les deux clans avait été racontée dans une publication avec des détails choquants/brutaux par un jeune journaliste.

If "graphic" is intented literaly, I still wouldn't use « détails graphiques » in French; it wouldn't be wrong, but unusual to a French ear. I would rather go with « dans les moindres détails » (literaly "down to the smallest items").

> La bagarre entre les deux clans avait été racontée dans les moindres détails dans une publication par un jeune journaliste.

Comment: You're very right as the first part of your explanation goes; that does fit the case; here is for instance the Oxford Avanced Learner's Dictionary's definition: (of description, etc;) very clear and full of details, **especially about sth unpleasant**. As to the other part it makes much sense; nevertheless, I am puzzled at the dilemma: why say one rather than the other only because the medium of communication differs? I do not even know which I should chose as a solution that would remain faithfull to the author's intent.

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding of the original sentence is correct, why not using "détails graphiques"? Thus I would interprete the original sentence as follows

> La bagarre entre les deux clans avait été racontée dans une publication en
>   détails graphiques par un jeune journaliste.

Ngram provides some verification about "détails graphiques".

[image]

---

**EDIT** ([damadam](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17289/damadam)'s version; see comment)

> La bagarre entre les deux clans avait été racontée dans une
>   publication avec des graphiques détaillés par une jeune journaliste.

Comment: Of course I would appreciate natives' opinion here :-)!

Comment: Fine with me, but if we treat all such problems in this way and dismiss them with the neologism  that constitutes a literal translation, have we really exploited the depth of the language or have we recognized (rather bluntly) that it does not have the proper ressources, as moreover we might add on to possibly an already plentiful pile of term?

Comment: @user168676 I don't understand. What is the neologism in here? See for instance: https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/graphic+detail.html

Comment: Then "détail graphique" must have been introduced in the language some time ago unless it' the other way around; I wasn't aware of that, sorry.

Comment: Non native here:-)! I suggest that you wait comments or/and answers by natives.

Comment: @ dimitris After following your suggestion ( linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/graphic+detail.html ) and reading along I found in the list "détails imagé", which I much prefer.

Comment: @dimitris your translation is pretty good, but I would change the "print" part, which didn't sound good; I would more say *La bagarre entre les deux clans avait été racontée dans une publication **avec des graphiques détaillés** par une jeune journalite*

Answer (score -1):

*détails imagés*, see [this Linguee query](https://linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/graphic+detail.html).

Comment: Détails graphiques, according to Ngram is used without problem. In any case, if you want to reply your question, you should combine the two answers into a single one.

Comment: Bear in mind that détails graphiques is more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9tails+graphiques%2Cd%C3%A9tails+vivides%2Cd%C3%A9tails+imag%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9tails%20graphiques%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9tails%20imag%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Agreed, and possibly it is useful to dispose of an additionnal term; synonyms in a language are without contest recognized as a necessity. Nevertheles, I think "imagé" to be "un terme consacré", already well established, that fits the bill perfectly so to speak.